# Reference a class from XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

In Silverlight5 how to reference a Thing class from XAML:

```
xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:xyz.ClientApp.UserControls"
```

```
 public class Thing : ContextMenu, IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            MethodInfo infos = typeof(ContextMenu).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(a => a.Name.Equals("HandleRootVisualMouseMove")).FirstOrDefault();

            Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MouseEventHandler), this, infos);

            EventInfo info = System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual.GetType().GetEvent("MouseMove");
            info.RemoveEventHandler(System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual, handler);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Am trying to fix a bug in ContextMenuService [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/6206)

Comment: Isn't it just `UserControls:Thing`?

Comment: Does Thing have the correct namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing attached properties and object instantiation syntax. ContextMenu is attached property of ContextMunueService and can not be accessed through your Thing class.

I havent tested it, but following code should work:

```
<controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
  <UserControls:Thing>
    <!-- menu items here -->
  </UserControls:Thing>
</controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks Denis.. ended up doing something slightly different and implementing manually http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/6206